# Many stacked ybars side-by-side at the same coordinate

Tags: pgfplots

I have several ybar stacked plots and I would like to put them together in one plot.

However, since the ybars of the different plots share the same coordinates, when I put them in one plot, they just stack up into a single ybar. However, I would like to have the original stacked ybars be displayed side by side at the given coordinate (just as non-stacked ybars do).

Anybody got an idea how to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple: use two `axis` environments and shift the bars a bit. If you are very picky, you need to change the `unit vector ratio` of one of the plots a bit.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=8cm,
    unit vector ratio=1 0.5, 
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e},
    xtick=data,
    ybar stacked,
    ytick pos=left,
    ]
        \addplot[ybar,fill=blue!30,mark=no,bar shift=-3mm] coordinates {
         (a,3.5)
         (b,0.75)
         (c,4.85)
         (d,3.33)
         (e,7)
        };
        \addplot[ybar,fill=orange,mark=no,bar shift=-3mm] coordinates {
         (a,2.5)
         (b,1.75)
         (c,1.85)
         (d,2.33)
         (e,1)
        };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[ytick=\empty,
    width=8cm,
    unit vector ratio=1 0.5, 
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e},
    xtick=data,
    ybar stacked,
    ytick pos=left,
    ]
        \addplot[ybar,fill=green!30,mark=no,bar shift=3mm] coordinates {
         (a,2.5)
         (b,1.75)
         (c,1.85)
         (d,2.33)
         (e,1)
        };
        \addplot[ybar,fill=red,mark=no,bar shift=3mm] coordinates {
         (a,3.5)
         (b,0.75)
         (c,4.85)
         (d,3.33)
         (e,7)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]